# Objects added to QList lose all of their member data

Tags: qt, list, member, qlist

I'm making a QList of a custom class called ControlIcon. I create the ControlIcons, and load them up with member variables, and then add them to the list. Here's the append code:

`this->cueList.append(firstOne);`

Here's the declaration of the QList:

`QList< ControlIcon *> cueList;`

If I break right after the append, I can see that the ControlIcon that was just added is full of members, and appears fine. I look in the list, and the ControlIcon that's been appended (and it does append a ControlIcon) has no members at all. I've made a QList of custom objects before, so I'm very confused. Could someone help?

Comment: Please show the code where firstOne is created and destructed.

Comment: So for some reasons you have two different pointers (firstOne and the one stored in QList)? firstOne still working, then the item in the list points to a different address?

Comment: How do you "look in" the list? If you are using Creator for debugging, it may have problem showing your class members in a container. I run into this sometime with Mac version of Creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data type of the list to be SerialController (the child of ControlIcon), which is what I was trying to add to it, and it works fine. This is really annoying, because there's other types of controllers, but I guess it will have to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class must be [assignable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/containers.html#assignable-data-type), that means it must provide a default constructor, a copy constructor and a assignment operator. If they don't, weird things like this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

`cueList` contains pointers to `ControlIcon` objects, but it is not responsible for creating or keeping those `ControlIcon` objects.  How did you get the pointer `firstOne`?  If it points to something on the stack, that object would be invalid when you try to use it later.  If it was created with `new`, it will stay valid until you clean it up using `delete`.

Comment: "SerialController *firstOne = new SerialController" is what I used create the Control Icon (SerialController is a child class of ControlIcon).